# Extension of Mantel's theorem

Tags: graph-theory

How would one extend the proof of Mantel's Theorem to show that if $G$ is a graph with $n$ vertices and $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor - t$ edges then $G$ contains a bipartite subgraph with at least $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor - 2t$ edges?

Comment: Since this is intended to be an extension of Mantel's Theorem, do you assume that $G$ is triangle-free?

Comment: Yes, we assume G has no K3.

Answer (score 4):

For every vertex $x$, we can let $A_x$ be all the neighbors of $x$ and $B_x$ be all the non-neighbors of $x$. Because $G$ is triangle-free, $A_x$ is an independent set, so if we delete all the edges in $E(B_x)$, we get a bipartite graph with bipartition $(A_x, B_x \cup \{x\})$.

It remains to choose a vertex $x$ for which $|E(B_x)|$ is small. What follows is just an elaboration on the one-line proof of Lemma 2.1 in ["How to make a graph bipartite"](http://combinatorica.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1988-12.pdf) by Erdős, Faudree, Pach, and Spencer.

We have
$$
    \sum_{x \in V(G)} |E(B_x)| = \sum_{vw \in E(G)} (n - \deg(v) - \deg(w)).
$$
The second sum counts for every edge $vw$ all the vertices not adjacent to $v$ or $w$: here we are using the fact that $G$ is triangle-free and therefore no vertex is adjacent to both. The vertices not adjacent to $v$ or $w$ are precisely the vertices $x$ for which $vw \in E(B_x)$. Therefore the two sums count pairs $(x, vw)$ where $vw \in E(B_x)$ in two different ways, so they're equal.

Expanding out the second sum, we get
$$
    \sum_{x \in V(G)} |E(B_x)| = \sum_{vw \in E(G)} (n - \deg(v) - \deg(w)) = n|E(G)| - \sum_{v \in V(G)} \deg(v)^2
$$
because $\deg(v)$ is subtracted once for each of the $\deg(v)$ edges out of $v$. By the convexity of $x \mapsto x^2$, or by Cauchy-Schwarz, the sum of squares is minimized when $\deg(v) = \frac{2|E(G)|}{n}$ for all $v$, and therefore
$$
    \sum_{x \in V(G)} |E(B_x)| = n|E(G)| - \sum_{v \in V(G)} \deg(v)^2 \le n|E(G)| - n \cdot \frac{4|E(G)|^2}{n^2}.
$$
If we substitute $|E(G)| = \frac{n^2}{4} - t$ into this inequality and simplify, the right-hand side becomes $n(\frac{n^2}{4}-t) - \frac{4}{n}(\frac{n^2}{4}-t)^2 = \frac{n^3}{4} - nt - \frac{n^3}{4} + 2nt - \frac{4t^2}{n} = nt - \frac{4t^2}{n}$, so we get
$$
    \sum_{x \in V(G)} |E(B_x)| \le tn - \frac{4t^2}{n} \iff \frac1n \sum_{x \in V(G)} |E(B_x)| \le t - \frac{4t^2}{n^2}
$$
and therefore there is some choice of $x$ for which $|E(B_x)| \le t - \frac{4t^2}{n^2}$. By deleting the edges of $B_x$ from $G$, we get a bipartite subgraph containing all but at most $ t - \frac{4t^2}{n^2}$ edges of $G$: therefore we have at least
$$
   \frac{n^2}{4} - t - \left(t - \frac{4t^2}{n^2}\right) = \frac{n^2}{4} - 2t + \frac{4t^2}{n^2} \ge \frac{n^2}{4} - 2t
$$
edges in the bipartite subgraph.

Comment: Dear Misha! May I ask you two questions? This is Exercise 1.1.5. in Yufei Zhao's book "Graph Theory and Additive Combinatorics". 1) Why does he label this problem as "stability"? 2) I don't follow why the author calls it as "an extension of Mantel's theorem". Thank you!

Comment: In extremal combinatorics, the weakest thing we can show is a simple condition such as Mantel's theorem "If a graph has no triangles, then it has at most $n^2/4$ edges". The next way to strengthen it is to describe the extreme cases: "...and we only reach $n^2/4$ if we have a complete bipartite graph". A "stability theorem" is the way to strengthen the result even further: "...and we can only get close to $n^2/4$ if we're close to a complete bipartite graph". Both instances of "close to" need to be quantified, and one way to do that is this exercise.

Comment: In general, a stability theorem is one that says "if the extremal value of some parameter can only be achieved by one of a few specific constructions, and we're looking at an object that's *close to extremal*, then it must resemble one of the constructions".

Comment: This is as far as I think it's worth elaborating in the comments; if you want to know more, it's best to post a separate question about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will read your comments. Why you partition the vertex set of graph $G$ as $A_x\cup B_x\cup \{x\}$? We suppose that $G$ is simple and hence $x\notin A_x$. But $x$ is an element of $B_x$, right?

Comment: I just wanted to make it clear that I want to include $x$ on the same side as $B_x$; if you like, define $B_x$ to contain $x$ right away and then the bipartition is just $(A_x, B_x)$.

Comment: Very neat and elegant solution! +1. I tried to solve this problem on my own and spent almost two days but did not make a big progress. Thank you so much Misha!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but I am bit confused. First of all we know that $e(G)=\lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor-t$. What you did in the end on the proof it refers to the case when $n$ is even number and I am completely agree with it. But when $n$ is odd, then there some issues with estimates. Indeed, if $n=2m+1$, then $e(G)=m^2+m-t$ and it follows that $$\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{x\in V(G)}|E(B_x)|\leq m^2+m-t-\frac{4}{(2m+1)^2}(m^2+m-t)^2=t+\frac{m^2+m-2t-4t^2}{(2m+1)^2}.$$ But it does not obvious that $m^2+m-2t-4t^2<0$.

Comment: Nevermind! In odd case the average is at most $t+1/4$ and one can proceed similarly as in even case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt: Consider a bipartition $(A,B)$ of the vertices of the graph $G$ such that the number of edges between the two bipartition is maximized. So then we can see that this bipartite subgraph $H$ has the property: $v \in V(H)$ then $deg(v)_{H} \geq \frac{deg(v)_G}{2}$. So $2|E(H)|=\sum_{v\in V(H)}deg(v) \geq \sum_{v\in V(G)}\frac{deg(v)}{2}=\frac{2|E(G)|}{2}=\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4} \rfloor -t$. so then $|E(H)|\geq \frac{\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4} \rfloor -t}{2}$.

Comment: can anyone complete the proof or give a solution?