# Existence of vertex in a triangle-free graph whose non-neighbours have at most $m(1-4m/n^2)$ edges.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

Given triangle-free graph $G=(V,E)$ and $n:=|V|$, $m:=|E|$. I would like to show that there is a vertex whose non-neighbours have at most $m(1-4m/n^2)$ edges, i.e. the graph $G[V\setminus N[v]]$ has at most $m(1-4m/n^2)$ edges. I tried approaching by contradiction and assuming that each such subgraph has at least the number of edges and maybe show that the graph has more than $n^2/4$ edges which would contradict Mantel's theorem but got nowhere.

Comment: See also: [Extension of Mantel's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/370398/383078)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Briefly reason like this.

Assume the contrary.

1. Suppose that for any vertex $v$ of graph $G$ we have
   $$
   |E(G-N(v))|>m-\frac{4m^2}{n^2}.
   $$
2. Since the graph $G$ has no triangles, then
   $$
   |E(G-N(v))|=m-\sum_{x\in N(v)}\operatorname{deg}(x).
   $$
3. It follows from 1) and 2) that
   $$
   \sum_{x\in N(v)}\operatorname{deg}(x)<\frac{4m^2}{n^2}.
   $$
4. Let us sum the last inequality over all vertices of graph $G$
   $$
   \sum_{v\in V(G)}\sum_{x\in N(v)}\operatorname{deg}(x)<\frac{4m^2}{n}.
   $$
5. Then
   $$
   \sum_{v\in V(G)}\sum_{x\in N(v)}\operatorname{deg}(x)=\sum_{v\in V(G)}(\operatorname{deg}(v))^2<\frac{4m^2}{n}.
   $$
6. The Cauchy–Schwarz inequality gives
   $$
   \frac{(\sum_{v\in V(G)}\operatorname{deg}(v))^2}{n}\leq\sum_{v\in V(G)}(\operatorname{deg}(v))^2<\frac{4m^2}{n}.
   $$
7. It follows that
   $\frac{(2m)^2}{n}< \frac{4m^2}{n}$.

Contradiction.

Comment: Great explanation and steps, may I just ask you to elaborate on the Cauchy Schwartz step? I am quite unsure, where it came from.

Comment: Nevermind, I have it now. Apply it for the vector $\vec{\deg v}\cdot \vec{1}$, where $\vec{1}$ is the vector of all $1$'s and $\vec{\deg v}$ is the vector of degrees.

Comment: Yes, absolutely right. And thank you for correcting my terrible typos.